# Perl on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows, perl, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Does Perl work on Windows Server 2008 (and Win Server 2008 R2)? Is there a distribution for these OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes it does. you need to get the active perl:
http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads

Answer (score 7):

There are several Perl distributions for Windows. The most common is [ActivePerl](http://activestate.com/activeperl/downloads). However, you can't use the standard [CPAN](http://cpan.perl.com) archive since you might not be able to compile some of the modules. Other people prefer [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) just for this reason. It comes with a compiler that works on Windows.